# table sorter- zebra stripping

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter, zebra-striping

I am using this table sorter with zebra stripping  . I am operating sort with the drop down menu options. I have two issues with that.

1) I have the rows colored grey and white alternatively. But i have some special rows with always grey color.

suppose if it is normal case i will have grey , white, grey order.

Now suppose the white row in the above is a special row which i am talking about. then it will be grey. so now we have three grey rows instead of grey white grey.

is there any way  zebra widget can inteligently notice that as the previous one is special row( always grey), it should make the current row as white.

Comment: I am guessing, that if i can say zebra widget to skip that special rows , my problem is solved. but how can i tell

Comment: Some code or an example might help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code (http://jsfiddle.net/cqN5W/):

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var i;
for (i in tables) {
    if (tables.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof tables[i] === "object") {
        var rows = tables[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var counter = 0;
        var j;
        for (j in rows) {
            if (rows.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                if (rows[j].className.indexOf("gray") === -1) {
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter % 2) {
                    rows[j].className += " gray";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will keep in mind which rows have been explicitly marked as "gray" and will factor those into its coloring.